# Read multiple CSVs with Spark that have different schemas from S3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have ~20k files per partition in S3 in this location:

```
s3://mybucket/schema/table/date=<date>/hour=<hour>
```

All of the files are CSV with header. Unfortunately, a few of the files can have an additional column **not at the end of the file**. If I do this:

```
df = self.spark.read.csv(
     self.input_loc,
     sep=",",
     inferSchema="false",
     header="true",
     ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace="true",
     ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace="true",
            )
```

Where `self.input_loc` is:

```
s3a://mybucket/schema/table/date=<date>/*
```

the variable `df` ends up having the columns shifted to the right for records coming from files that did have the additional column. I can't really pass the schema directly, but I am very surprised that Spark isn't catching this on its own out of the box.

How do I tell Spark to check the schemas of all the files? I was under the impression that with `inferSchema` set to false and the default of `samplingRatio` being 1 and `header` set to true, that all the data would be scanned to determine the schema for the DF. I don't mind if the data has to be scanned more than once.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are the column names standard across all files? If so, you can select only the standard columns you need, and discard the rest.

For example, if your files contain columns:

file1: ["name","age","uneeded1"],

file2: ["name","uneeded2","age"],

file3: ["uneeded3","name","age"]

```
df = df.select("name", "age")
```